# Is there a formula to build parameter messages to be passed to smart contract entrypoints?

Tags: smart-contracts, michelson, smartpy, micheline, json

When calling a smart contract entrypoint, it is required to pass the needed entrypoint parameters. This is done through a message that must be sent in JSON/Pairs format. My doubt is: Is there a formula to build these parameter messages to be passed to smart contract entrypoints?

For example, when calling the addCustomer entrypoint from SmartPy Explorer:

[image]

[image]

It generates the correspondent Michelson message:

(Left (Left (Pair (Pair 8000000 "0001") (Pair Älice"99999897))))

Is there a formula to calculate programmatically the number of LEFTs and RIGHTs, maybe according to the number of entrypoints or even parameters?

[image]

Any information will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have created once a routine that worked well to do this, until the protocol change to Carthage. Then, apparently the order of the LEFTs and RIGHTs changed somehow. I would like to know the recommended way to do it, so I can avoid future problems after new protocol upgrades.

Comment: Carthage brought no change regarding the treatment of entrypoints, you see a difference because you are calling different contracts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to indicate which entrypoint you want to call:

- call it by its name using the `--entrypoint` command-line argument of `tezos-client transfer` or the `entrypoint` optional parameter of the corresponding RPCs. If you do this, you can simply pass the argument of the expected entrypoint type without the leading `Left`s and `Right`s.
- call it by its position in the `parameter` type of the smart contract: the parameter type can be seen as a binary tree whose nodes are labeled by `or`, you can indicate an entrypoint by a giving the path composed of `Left`s and `Right`s from the root of this tree. An example is given [in the Michelson documentation](https://tezos.gitlab.io/whitedoc/michelson.html#entrypoints).

Answer (score 2):

If we could do a logic schematics for this specific case, do you sirs think it could be described like this? :

parameter (or (or (pair %addCustomer (pair (mutez %balance) (string %id)) (pair (string %name) (nat %phoneNumber))) (string %removeCustomer)) (or (pair %transfer (mutez %amount) (pair (string %idFrom) (string %idTo))) (pair %updateBalance (mutez %amount) (string %id))))    :

[image]

Comment: A few remarks: 
1. I like it
2. update is update Balance
3. I don't fully understand the UNIT but otherwise, it seems pretty accurate to me.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. I think this kind of visual thing is important for new Tezos developers. It definetely helps to understand some details. I will edit the image to match your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the path to the corresponding entry point in the Michelson parameter type. ‘Left’ when you go to the left branch of a ‘or’ and ‘Right’ for the right branch.

Answer (score 0):

After this important discussion I've ended with a functional solution which I am sharing  here with whoever might find useful. This code is in Java. Details of it might be found on [TezosJ_plainJava github repository](https://github.com/TezosRio/TezosJ_plainJava).

The method "solvePair" transforms recursively a "Pair" of parameters into the expected JSON/Pairs format that is needed to be passed to Tezos smart contracts entrypoints, making it easy for developers to interact with Tezos blockchain.

Example:

INPUT:

Pair      : (([1000000],[2000000,003]),([001],[005,002]))

Datatypes : [ "int", "int", "String", "String", "String", "String" ]

OUTPUT:

{ "prim": "Pair", "args": [ { "prim": "Pair", "args": [ { "int": "1000000" }, { "prim": "Pair", "args": [ { "int": "2000000" }, { "string": "003" } ] } ] }, { "prim": "Pair", "args": [ { "string": "001" }, { "prim": "Pair", "args": [ { "string": "005" }, { "string": "002" } ] } ] } ] }

Here are the routines:

```
   private Object solvePair(Object pair, List datatypes) throws Exception
   {
         
      Object result = null;
      
      // Extract and check contents.
      if (hasPairs((Pair) pair) == false)
      {
         // Here we've got List in both sides. But they might have more than one element.
         Object jsonLeft  = ((Pair) pair).getLeft() == null ? null : toJsonFormat((List)((Pair) pair).getLeft(), datatypes, 0);
         Object jsonRight = ((Pair) pair).getRight() == null ? null : toJsonFormat((List)((Pair) pair).getRight(), datatypes, ((Pair) pair).getLeft() == null ? 0 : ((List)((Pair) pair).getLeft()).size() );
         
         // Test if there is only one parameter.
         if (jsonLeft == null)
            if (jsonRight == null)
               throw new Exception("Pair cannot be (null, null)");
            else
               return jsonRight;
         else if (jsonRight == null)
            return jsonLeft;

         // Build json outter pair.
         JSONObject jsonPair = new JSONObject();
         jsonPair.put("prim", "Pair");
         
         // Create pair contents array.
         JSONArray pairContents = new JSONArray();
         pairContents.put(jsonLeft);
         pairContents.put(jsonRight);
         jsonPair.put("args", pairContents);
         
         return jsonPair;
      }
      else
      {
         Object jsonLeft = solvePair(((Pair<Pair, List>) pair).getLeft(), datatypes);
         Object jsonRight = solvePair(((Pair<Pair, List>) pair).getRight(), datatypes.subList( countPairElements((Pair) ((Pair) pair).getLeft()), datatypes.size()) );
         
         // Build json outter pair.
         JSONObject jsonPair = new JSONObject();
         jsonPair.put("prim", "Pair");
         
         // Create pair contents array.
         JSONArray pairContents = new JSONArray();
         pairContents.put(jsonLeft);
         pairContents.put(jsonRight);
         jsonPair.put("args", pairContents);
         
         return jsonPair;
      }

   }

   private Integer countPairElements(Pair pair)
   {
      Integer leftCount = 0;
      Integer rightCount = 0;
      
      Object left = pair.getLeft();
      Object right = pair.getRight();

      if(left instanceof Pair)
      {
         leftCount = countPairElements((Pair) left);
      }
      else
      {
         leftCount = ((List)left).size();
      }
      
      if(right instanceof Pair)
      {
         rightCount = countPairElements((Pair) right);
      }
      else
      {
         rightCount = ((List)right).size();
      }

      return leftCount+rightCount;

   }
   
   private Boolean hasPairs(Pair pair)
   {
      Object left = pair.getLeft();
      Object right = pair.getRight();
      
      if( (left instanceof Pair) || (right instanceof Pair) )
      {
         return true;
      }
      else
      {
         return false;
      }
   }
   
   private JSONObject toJsonFormat(List list, List datatypes, Integer firstElement)
   { 
      JSONArray result = new JSONArray();
            
      for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
      {
         JSONObject element = new JSONObject();
         element.put((String) datatypes.get(firstElement + i), list.get(i));
       
         // Add element to array.
         result.put(element);
      }
               
      if (result.length() > 1)
      {
         // Wrap json result in outter pair.
         JSONObject jsonPair = new JSONObject();
         jsonPair.put("prim", "Pair");
         jsonPair.put("args", result);   
         
         return jsonPair;
      }
      else
      {
         return (JSONObject)result.get(0);
      }

   }
```

And if you wish to build a Pair object from a String[] parameter array, you might use the routine below.

INPUT: empty JSONObject, empty Pair, List of your parameters values (like String[] {"param1", "param2", "param3"} ).

OUTPUT: (param1,(param2,param3))

```
   private Pair buildParameterPairs(JSONObject jsonObj, Pair pair, List<String> parameters,
                                    String[] contractEntryPointParameters,
                                    Boolean doSolveLeft) throws Exception
   {
      
      // Test parameters validity.
      if (parameters.isEmpty())
      {
         throw new Exception("Missing parameters to pass to contract entrypoint");
      }

      List<String> left = new ArrayList<String>();
      List<String> right = new ArrayList<String>();
      Pair newPair = null;
      
      if(parameters.size() == 1)
      {         
         // If number of parameters is only 1.
         newPair = new MutablePair<>(null, new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(parameters.get(0))));
      }
      else 
      {

         if (pair == null)
         {
            Integer half = ( Math.abs(parameters.size() / 2) );

            left = parameters.subList(0, half);
            right = parameters.subList(half, parameters.size());

            newPair = new MutablePair<>(left, right);
                        
         }
         else
         {
            List<String> newList;
            
            if (doSolveLeft == true)
            {
               newList = ((List<String>) pair.getLeft());
            }
            else
            {
               newList = ((List<String>) pair.getRight());
            }
            
            Integer half = ( Math.abs( newList.size() / 2) );

            left = newList.subList(0, half);
            right = newList.subList(half, newList.size());

            newPair = new MutablePair<>(left, right);
            
         }

         
         if (  (((List)newPair.getRight()).size() > 2) || (((List)newPair.getLeft()).size() > 2)  )
         {

               newPair = new MutablePair<>(buildParameterPairs(jsonObj, newPair, parameters, contractEntryPointParameters, true),
                                           buildParameterPairs(jsonObj, newPair, parameters, contractEntryPointParameters, false));

         }
         else
         {
            return newPair;
         }

      }

      return newPair;

   }
```